# How to allow apis inside docker-compose.yml to be used

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is the compose.yml file I made but whenever I send a request to http://127.0.0.1/ it does not respond. I was wondering if anyone knew the answer.

```
services:
  database:
    image: 'database'
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: ./database
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-u cassandra", "-p cassandra" ,"-e describe keyspaces"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
    expose:
      - '0.0.0.0:9042:9042'

  backend:
    image: 'backend'
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: ./src/backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ENDPOINT_URL
      - SCYLLADB_IPS
    expose:
      - '0.0.0.0:443:443'
```

I expected the API in image 'backend' to send back a responce. Its an exspressjs API.

Comment: The port you expose Is 443 so you should use `https`.

Comment: Changed it to 8080 still not working

Comment: Also replace `expose` with `ports`, see https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-compose-expose-vs-ports

Comment: It looks like you're disabling Docker's networking system entirely with `network_mode: host`.  This shouldn't be necessary (and you should get a warning with @Pino's suggestion), does deleting these lines help at all?